# I can't play a DVD using VLC

Tags: video, vlc, dvd

I can't play "Dr. Strangelove" on VLC... it just comes up on the screen and then does nothing. Pressing play does nothing.

using Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: install the QUICKTIME -lib and -util via Synaptic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir! I have a plan!

If it is a DVD:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs